# Correct way to setup a RegisterHandler

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, networking

I have a client-side script that needs to listen for a server message. The server side of things seems to be working properly but, as I'm very new to networking I'm still trying to piece things together. I am configuring and connecting using Unity's NetworkTransport API. Where I'm stuck is how to create my client-side register handler correctly to receive an incoming message type from the server.

From the server, I'm sending via :

```
public void SendTexture(Texture2D tex, string type, int id, int strength, int hitpoints)
    {
        TextureMessage msg = new TextureMessage();

        //Convert Texture2D to byte array

        msg.Tex = tex.GetRawTextureData();
        msg.Type = type;
        msg.Id = id;
        msg.Strength = strength;
        msg.Hitpoints = hitpoints;

        NetworkServer.SendToAll(MyMsgType.texture, msg);
    }
```

But I'm unsure how to structure the receiving side of things on the client. The furthest I got was this but I'm already breaking things :

```
    public void setupRegisterHandler()
    {
        //Register to texture receive event
        NetworkClient.RegisterHandler(MyMsgType.texture, OnTextureReceive);
    }

    public void OnTextureReceive(NetworkMessage netMsg)
{
    TextureMessage msg = netMsg.ReadMessage<TextureMessage>();

    string type = msg.Type;
    Debug.Log("Type : " + type);

    int id = msg.Id;
    Debug.Log("ID : " + id);

    int strength = msg.Strength;
    Debug.Log("Strength : " + strength);

    int hitpoints = msg.Hitpoints;
    Debug.Log("Hit Points : " + hitpoints);

    //Your Received Texture2D
    Texture2D receivedtexture = new Texture2D(1280, 1024);
    receivedtexture.LoadRawTextureData(msg.Tex);
    receivedtexture.Apply();
}
```

From the line `NetworkClient.RegisterHandler(MyMsgType.texture, OnTextureReceive);` I'm getting the error `'Assets/Scripts/Client.cs(106,17): error CS0120: An object reference is required to access non-static member 'UnityEngine.Networking.NetworkClient.RegisterHandler(short, UnityEngine.Networking.NetworkMessageDelegate)'`

How do I setup my setupRegisterHandler() function correctly? I've been struggling with networking for nearly a month now and I feel like I'm so close! I've also included the full scripts below for reference if you need them. Thank you!

Client script

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.Networking;

public class Client : MonoBehaviour {

    private const int MAX_CONNECTION = 100;

    private string serverIP = "127.0.0.1";
    private int port = 5701;
    private int hostId;
    private int webHostId;
    private int reliableChannel;
    private int reliableSeqChannel;
    private int reliableFragChannel;
    private int unreliableChannel;
    private int unreliableSeqChannel;

    private int ourClientId;
    private string playerName;
    private int connectionId;

    private float connectionTime;
    private bool isStarted = false;
    private bool isConnected = false;
    private byte error;

    private GameObject infoDisplayText;

    private void Awake()
    {
        infoDisplayText = GameObject.Find("InfoDisplay");
    }

    private void Start()
    {
        Connect();
    }

    private void Connect()
    {
        NetworkTransport.Init();

        ConnectionConfig cc = new ConnectionConfig();

        reliableChannel = cc.AddChannel(QosType.Reliable);
        reliableSeqChannel = cc.AddChannel(QosType.ReliableSequenced);
        reliableFragChannel = cc.AddChannel(QosType.ReliableFragmented);
        unreliableChannel = cc.AddChannel(QosType.Unreliable);
        unreliableSeqChannel = cc.AddChannel(QosType.UnreliableSequenced);
        cc.PacketSize = 1024;

        HostTopology topo = new HostTopology(cc, MAX_CONNECTION);

        hostId = NetworkTransport.AddHost(topo, 0);

        // Run client/server on different machines
        //hostID = NetworkTransport.AddHost(topo, port, null);  

        connectionId = NetworkTransport.Connect(hostId, serverIP, port, 0, out error);

        infoDisplayText.GetComponent<Text>().text += playerName + " connected.\n";

        connectionTime = Time.time;
        isConnected = true;

        setupRegisterHandler();
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (!isConnected)
            return;

        int recHostId;
        int connectionId;
        int channelId;
        byte[] recBuffer = new byte[1024];
        int bufferSize = 1024;
        int dataSize;
        byte error;

        NetworkEventType recData = NetworkTransport.Receive(out recHostId, out connectionId, out channelId, recBuffer, bufferSize, out dataSize, out error);

        switch (recData)
        {
            case NetworkEventType.ConnectEvent:
                Debug.Log("Player " + connectionId + " has connected");
                infoDisplayText.GetComponent<Text>().text += "Player " + connectionId + " has connected\n";
                break;

            case NetworkEventType.DataEvent:
                break;

            case NetworkEventType.DisconnectEvent:
                break;
        }
    }

    public void setupRegisterHandler()
    {
        //Register to texture receive event
        NetworkClient.RegisterHandler(MyMsgType.texture, OnTextureReceive);
    }

    //Called when texture is received
    public void OnTextureReceive(NetworkMessage netMsg)
    {
        TextureMessage msg = netMsg.ReadMessage<TextureMessage>();

        //Your Received message
        string message = msg.Type;
        Debug.Log("Texture Messsage " + message);

        //Your Received Texture2D
        Texture2D receivedtexture = new Texture2D(1280, 1024);
        receivedtexture.LoadRawTextureData(msg.Tex);
        receivedtexture.Apply();
    }
}
```

Server script

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.Networking;

public class Server : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Texture2D texToSend;
    string typeToSend = "Deer";
    int idToSend = 1;
    int strengthToSend = 80;
    int hitPointsToSend = 2;

    private const int MAX_CONNECTION = 100;
    private int port = 5701;
    private int hostId;
    private int webHostId;
    private int reliableChannel;
    private int reliableSeqChannel;
    private int reliableFragChannel;
    private int unreliableChannel;
    private int unreliableSeqChannel;

    private bool isStarted = false;
    private byte error;

    private GameObject infoDisplayText;

    private void Awake()
    {
        infoDisplayText = GameObject.Find("InfoDisplay");
    }

    private void Start()
    {
        NetworkTransport.Init();

        ConnectionConfig cc = new ConnectionConfig();

        reliableChannel = cc.AddChannel(QosType.Reliable);
        reliableSeqChannel = cc.AddChannel(QosType.ReliableSequenced);
        reliableFragChannel = cc.AddChannel(QosType.ReliableFragmented);
        unreliableChannel = cc.AddChannel(QosType.Unreliable);
        unreliableSeqChannel = cc.AddChannel(QosType.UnreliableSequenced);
        cc.PacketSize = 1024;

        HostTopology topo = new HostTopology(cc, MAX_CONNECTION);

        hostId = NetworkTransport.AddHost(topo, port, null);

        if (NetworkTransport.IsStarted)
        {
            isStarted = true;
            Debug.Log("NetworkTransport is Started.");
            infoDisplayText.GetComponent<Text>().text += "NetworkTransport is Started.\n";
        }

        Debug.Log("Server Started.");
        infoDisplayText.GetComponent<Text>().text += "Server Started.\n";
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (!isStarted)
            return;

        int recHostId;
        int connectionId;
        int channelId;
        byte[] recBuffer = new byte[1024];
        int bufferSize = 1024;
        int dataSize;
        byte error;

        NetworkEventType recData = NetworkTransport.Receive(out recHostId, out connectionId, out channelId, recBuffer, bufferSize, out dataSize, out error);

        switch (recData)
        {
            case NetworkEventType.ConnectEvent:
                Debug.Log("Player " + connectionId + " has connected");
                infoDisplayText.GetComponent<Text>().text += "Player " + connectionId + " has connected\n";
                break;

            case NetworkEventType.DataEvent:
                break;

            case NetworkEventType.DisconnectEvent:
                break;
        }
    }

    public void SendOnButtonPress()
    {
        SendTexture(texToSend, typeToSend, idToSend, strengthToSend, hitPointsToSend);
    }

    //Call to send the Texture and a simple string message
    public void SendTexture(Texture2D tex, string type, int id, int strength, int hitpoints)
    {
        TextureMessage msg = new TextureMessage();

        //Convert Texture2D to byte array

        msg.Tex = tex.GetRawTextureData();
        msg.Type = type;
        msg.Id = id;
        msg.Strength = strength;
        msg.Hitpoints = hitpoints;

        NetworkServer.SendToAll(MyMsgType.texture, msg);

        Debug.Log("Message of texture size of " + msg.Tex.Length + ", string size of " + msg.Type.Length + ", id of " + msg.Id + ", strength of " + msg.Strength + ", and hit points of " + msg.Hitpoints + " was sent!");

        infoDisplayText.GetComponent<Text>().text += "Message of texture size of " + msg.Tex.Length + ", string size of " + msg.Type.Length + ", id of " + msg.Id + ", strength of " + msg.Strength + ", and hit points of " + msg.Hitpoints + " was sent!\n";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NetworkClient` is not a component so you have to create new instance of it like a normal class using the `new` keyword. You can then use that new instance to call the `RegisterHandler` function.

```
NetworkClient client = new NetworkClient();
client.RegisterHandler(MyMsgType.texture, OnTextureReceive);
```